# Angular, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input when moving to production

Tags: angular, docker, webpack

We have a new Angular 8 application. Compiling using 'ng build' and 'ng build --prod' all work well locally.
But when compiling and dockerizing via a CI gitlab pipeline and deploying to kubernetes, we are experiencing 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input'. Compiling this app without the --prod switch, reveals that the problem is one of the node_module:

```
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["vendor"],{

/***/ "./node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/animations.js":
/*!**************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/animations.js ***!
  \**************************************************************/
```

and the problem seems to be that the file is indeed broken and ends with:

```
ViewportRuler.prototype.ngOnDestroy = /**
 * @return {?}
 */
function () {
```

which explains the error. Thinking this might be related to webpack, we upgraded to the following, but this only seems to have moved the problem to a different line in the code:

```
"webpack": "^4.42.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
```

How to fix this error which is completely outside our code? Is this really a webpack issue?

**UPDATE**: I had noticed that the problem is the following: it seems like the javascript files do not download in full. At first I thought that webpack doesn't generate the entire file. But when I tried to explicitly download by using the exact url as the app, I noticed that it looks correct and full. For some reason, when they get loaded via the angular app, its as if the browser times out on the file. Although returns a 200 OK, the devtools' Network/Response tab is showing that the file is actually not downloaded in full. Any idea why and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the nginx:alpine docker image was not gzip compressing the files. I included a new config file within the docker image containing some gzip configurations:

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/x-icon image/bmp image/svg+xml application/javascript;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
```

in the docker file (partial):

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/nginx-http.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

I still am puzzled by this. Even without the gzip, why would the browser stop loading the js files? Is there some timeout configured at browser level for downloading script files? I don't recall ever encountering such a behavior before.